# JS Monad unit function

Tags: javascript, functional-programming, monads

I'm struggling with understanding the unit function in JavaScript. Particularly because the thing that made me 'get' monads (or at least I thought) was the Promise object, and how `then` always returns a new Promise, regardless of what function you pass to `then`, which, to my knowledge is equivalent to `bind` or `>>=` in haskell. This totally makes sense to me, because it ensures that all of your functions are executed in the 'monad universe', so to speak.

What's tripping me up is the 'Monads and Gonads' talk by Douglas Crockford. In his implementation, `bind` directly returns the result of the transform function, without checking if the result itself, is a monad. This clashes with Promises's `then` method, as `then` ALWAYS returns a new Promise.

One thought was the lift method. His implementation does ensure that 'lift' will always return a monad, and maybe `then` was lifted on to Promise. However, this would mean that `then !== bind`, and that Promise has an internal bind somewhere.

My intuition is that there should at least be some sort of type check in the bind function that checks the result of the transformation, and allows a resulting monad to be let through, but will intercept non-monads and pass them through unit again, like 'lift' does.

*EDIT
Also, I'm under the impression that `then` is equivalent to `bind, flatMap, >>=` because it has the ability to unwrap other monads, including different ones and ones of it's own type. While looking in to some category theory references in JavaScript, `flatMap` was used to map over a set of nested arrays, and then flatten them by one dimension. This fits with how `then` will wait for other promises you give it. But doesn't seem to match up with the original implementation mentioned above. I feel lost.

Can anyone with more FP experience shed some light on what I'm missing, or am I just too off, and need to start from the beginning?

Some code examples...

```
// Crockford's 'bind'
monad.bind = function(transform) {
  // value was passed in through the unit constructor
  return transform(value);  
}
```

My trouble area

```
// Set the 'isMonad' prop to be true, for all
// monads made with the MONAD macroid
monad.isMonad = true;

// shouldn't this ALWAYS return a monad?
monad.bind = function(transform) {
  var res = transform(value);
  return ( res && res.isMonad ) ? res : unit(res);
}
```

*NOTE* I know i'm not using the final version of his implementation in full, I'm just focusing in the bind method in particular.

The full implementation can be found at

https://github.com/douglascrockford/monad/blob/master/monad.js

## *Update*

After doing some more research, `>>=` is not required to return a Monad instance. Bergi's comment shed some light on how `Promise.prototype.then` is overloaded and acts as a different function depending on what you resolve it with.

Also, a lot of things started to click when I took a step back and looked at how Monads are different from regular functors. The details are still a little fuzzy, but I think I get the big picture.

A few good references that helped clear the haze,

This one is highly recommend for a high level overview, in human words
http://adit.io/posts/2013-04-17-functors,_applicatives,_and_monads_in_pictures.html
Don't let the pictures fool you, this one was like gold for me. Not in JavaScript, but still very informative about the overall concepts.

Also, this YouTube series on Category Theory in JavaScript
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=-FkgOHvNAU8&list=PLwuUlC2HlHGe7vmItFmrdBLn6p0AS8ALX&index=1

This YouTube series called 'Fun Fun Function' is wonderful, the host is one of the best teachers I've found online. This video is about monads and was suggested by `MrE`.
Highly recommended!.

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=9QveBbn7t_c&app=desktop

Those two references specifically did wonders for me. Hope that helps everyone else as well.

Comment: I strongly recommend you ignore this Crockford talk/code.  Your understanding from promises is reasonable.  You should find it a *good* indicator that you find Crockford's talk confusing because he is confused.

Comment: `then` is a horrible implementation of a monad. It does mix `bind`/`chain`/`flatMap`/whatever you call it with a normal `map`, and it also accepts any thenables as return values. In Haskell, you absolutely don't need `isMonad`, because the compiler already checks that the function you pass in has the correct return type.

Comment: Add one more recommendation for "ignore Crockford".

Comment: Seems to be a common trend, thanks for the answers everyone.

Comment: i like this explanation: http://m.youtube.com/watch?v=9QveBbn7t_c

Comment: Hey @MrE, thanks for the comment. Funfunfunction is one of my favorite series, but that video led to more questions than answers for me. I watched before posting the original question, and is the reason why I chose to use Promise.prototype.then as an example. Mpj did a really good job in helping me 'get' monads, but this question was diving a little deeper than that video goes into. Great video though. Thanks again for the comment, I'll add that video above.

Comment: Just an additional comment on your question: monads and type checking are related but separate notions; you can implement monads in an either statically typed, dynamically typed, or untyped language; in other words, you can but do not necessarily have to check the types of values given to or returned by bind etc.  Of course, dynamic checking is better than no checking at all, and static checking is even better if possible.  Hope this helps!

Comment: Promise is neither a Functor nor a Monad: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/45712106/why-are-promises-monads/50173415#50173415

Answer (score 1):

I don't quite get what your question is, but I'd assume something like:

> what is the correct definition of a Monad and it's two methods in terms of JS?

In *Haskell* terms (taken from https://en.wikibooks.org/wiki/Haskell/Understanding_monads), it's simple:

```
    return :: a -> m a
    (>>=)  :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b

    (>>)   :: m a -> m b -> m b
```

For *JavaScript* terms, look no further, the short and simple answer is here https://github.com/fantasyland/fantasy-land#monad
along with other connected FP definitions.

Few words on the methods:

1. One thing is `unit` (`return` in *Haskell*) must produce a monad (not precisely monad, but for sake of argument...), since it's like a constructor that puts a value inside the container. `Array.of()` is one example, `jQuery()` is another, and of course `new Promise()` as well.

   In the *Fantasy Land Specification* this is the `of()` function/method.
2. The second one is important only because *Haskell* uses a definition of  monad having `unit` and `bind` while others (`fmap`,`join`) are inferred form them.

   The *Haskell's* `bind` is named `chain` in the *Fantasy Land Specification* because`bind` is defied on `Function.prototype` in *JavaScript*, so someone thought `chain` would be close enough.

   And the reason why `bind` i.e. `chain` "must" return a monad of the same type is because of
   `(>>=) :: m a -> (a -> m b) -> m b`. In short, the *Haskell's* `bind` function must only accept a function that returns a monad (this part `a -> m b`), so you're getting the result of it.
3. The *Haskell's* `then`

   > is a mere convenience

   and

   > sequences two monadic actions when the second action does not involve the result of the first, which is common for monads like IO.

In practice:

1. It may irk you in JS, since there is no strict type enforcement, that you can always not follow the rules and return whatever you want from a `Promise`, for example, thus breaking the `.then()` chain of said promise(s).
2. Some monads like `jQuery` have "lifted" functions as methods that always return `jQuery` i.e. of the same type thus "protecting" the ability to chain.

Comment: You don't need the third one: `(>>)   :: m a -> m b -> m b`, the first two suffice.

Comment: if there is a need, there is a way i.e. the need is to have a convenient shortcut for a common scenario